# I am practicing Angular JS in Brackets. While using Value Recipe, I am not getting correct output

Tags: html, angularjs

I am not getting the expected message when using value recipe.

I am getting output as `{{message}}`, but I am expecting `"hai services are working!!"`

Please share where I am going wrong.

HTML code: Injector.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Practicing Angular JS</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>   
        <script src="Injector.js"></script> <!-- Injector module file name -->

    </head>


 <body ng-app="injectormodule">   <!-- root module-->


<div ng-controller="controllerInjector"> 
    {{message}} 
    <!-- controller name-->

     </div>  


    </body>

</html>
```

Controller: Injector.js

```
var app = angular.module("injectormodule", ["servicemodule"])//name of service is servicemodule
    .controller("controllerInjector", ["$scope", "message", function($scope, message){
        $scope.message = message;
}]);
```

Service:(Value Recipe)

```
var myapp = angular.module("servicemodule", [])
    .value("message", "hai services are working!!");
```

Comment: You should inject your service into the controller not in the module. Well, seeing that's not a service just a value. And it's the same, you injectit into the controller of what you want use it.

Comment: I tried like below, but I am still getting {{message}} as output.  angular.module("injectormodule", [])//name of service is servicemodule
    .controller("controllerInjector", ["$scope", "message" "servicemodule" function($scope, message, servicemodule){
        $scope.message = message;
    }]);

Answer (score 0):

You need to Inject your `service` into `controller` and need to create same module.
See this sample working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mvdmh9x2/) which use service method to get text.

See other fiddle link also in comments

Comment: How can I inject service into controller? How to create same module? Below is my code, i am i doing correct?    angular.module("injectormodule", ["servicemodule"])//name of service is servicemodule
    .controller("controllerInjector", ["$scope", "message", function($scope, message){
        $scope.message = message;
    }]);
angular.module("injectormodule", ["servicemodule"])//name of service is servicemodule
    .controller("servicemodule", ["$scope", "message", function($scope, message){
        $scope.message = message;
    }]);

Comment: @Sourabh : see the attached fiddle example in answer.

Comment: I have changed Injector.js like below, but I am still getting same output as {{message}}. fiddle example is confusing I don't understand it.   angular.module("injectormodule", [])//name of service is servicemodule
    .controller("controllerInjector", ["$scope", "message" "servicemodule" function($scope, message, servicemodule){
        $scope.message = message;
    }]);

Comment: @Sourabh: If you just want to use `.value()`, then no need of service here. See this [Value fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/s1a3tqrc/). and If you want both then create 2 properties and get data from both source. See this [Service Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/d6dcgqya/)

Comment: sorry for late reply, it's not working. shed some light.

Comment: @Sourabh : did you tried fiddle mentioned in above comment ?, which uses `.value()`

Answer (score 0):

You have to define your `servicemodule` **before** your `injectormodule`, otherwise its creation will fail (since unable to find the `servicemodule` dependence).

Since the `injectormodule` failed from being created, the `ng-app="injectormodule"` will also be unable to bootstrap Angular on your DOM, thus won't interpret things like double brackets (`{{ message }}`).

Here is a working [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EWzBmZ).